# How to insert from file by SlideID

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint slide library and numerous presentations. I want to use a macro (VBA) to find a particular slide by SlideID (or some other marker, tag) in all open presentations, delete that slide, then insert in the same location an updated slide from my Slide Library. 
This step works:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(1296).Delete
```

where do I go from there to `InsertFromFile` a specific slide with its own `SlideID`?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You seem to have a fairly decent understanding of what needs to happen. You'll need to Copy the slide from the "library" presentation and insert it into the destination Presentation(s). I'm pretty sure the SlideID is read-only and assigned directly by PowerPoint, so you will not be able to maintain the same SlideId on the newly inserted slide.

Comment: Thanks, but  I don't know how to do that. Just a beginner. If my "library" is the active presentation, I assume I can "copy" a specific slide using SlideID. Then paste it into the destination presentation. I get the copy part, but I don't know how to paste into another presentation or a new presentation. I'm essentially try to "build" a new presentation with a selected number of slides from the Library.

Answer (score 0):

The following macro will first retrieve the slide index for the specified slide ID from the specified presentation, and then insert the slide into the active presentation.

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertSlideFromFileBySlideID()

    Dim sourcePresentation As Presentation
    Dim sourceFile As String
    Dim sourceSlideID As Long
    Dim sourceSlideIndex As Long

    sourceFile = "c:\users\domenic\desktop\sample.pptx" 'change the path and filename accordingly

    sourceSlideID = 256 'change the ID accordingly

    Set sourcePresentation = Application.Presentations.Open(FileName:=sourceFile, ReadOnly:=msoTrue)

    sourceSlideIndex = sourcePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(sourceSlideID).slideIndex

    sourcePresentation.Close

    'Insert the slide from the source file that has the specified slide index number at the end of the active presentation
    With ActivePresentation
        .Slides.InsertFromFile FileName:=sourceFile, Index:=.Slides.Count, SlideStart:=sourceSlideIndex, SlideEnd:=sourceSlideIndex
    End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

The following macro will copy multiple slides, by SlideID, from the specified open presentation to the active presentation.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopySlidesBySlideID()

    Dim sourcePresentation As Presentation
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sourcePresentation = Application.Presentations("sample.pptx") 'change the name accordingly
    If sourcePresentation Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Source presentation not found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim vSlideIDs As Variant
    vSlideIDs = Array(256, 260, 258) 'change the slide IDs accordingly

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(vSlideIDs) To UBound(vSlideIDs)
        sourcePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(vSlideIDs(i)).Copy
        ActivePresentation.Slides.Paste
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your generous help. I get a run-time error: "Slides "unknown member) : Integer out of range. 8 is not in the valid range of 0 to 4." [The active presentation has four slides...] // I'm not sure why I need the index, frankly. // Is there a way to have my Library of slides as the active presentation and build a new presentation by ordering up say a dozen sides from the Library by simply calling their SlideID and inserting??

Comment: The error means that the source file does not contain a slide that has the specified ID.  Is this in fact the case?  If not, did you change the ID specified in the code to the one you want?  Note that the slide ID is different than its index number.

Comment: If the presentation containing the library of slides is open, then you can simply copy slides by name, index, or slideID, and paste to your destination presentation.

Comment: Re. your first comment, still didn't work. It appears to be trying to put and 8 where there is only 0 to 4. Those look like slide numbers in the target file and not a slide ID in the source file.

Comment: Re. you second comment, I'm sure you're right, but  I actually don't know how to write the VBA for that. Sorry, mate!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  See my edited post, where I've corrected the part that inserts the slide from the file.

Comment: Dominic. Fantastic result. I have decided to leave the source file open on the screen because it's large and gets hung up otherwise. That works. I also have experimented with adding three different slides in succession from the source file, which works, though the macro is long. Is there any easy way to streamline the macro? What I did was just copy/paste  source file line through "end with" and changed the slideID.

Comment: Works like a charm. Is there a more *concrete* way I can offer my thanks by having you e-mail me at paul.horvitz@gmail.com? I may wish to offer an incentive to provide one other piece of VBA assistance: how can I copy one slide (by SlideID) from the source file so that it replaces the exact same Slide (with the same ID) in all open presentations?

Comment: You can simply thank me by accepting my post as the answer. :-)

Comment: As far as your other question, start a new thread and post a new question, along with the code that you tried, and someone will likely be able to provide you with a solution.